# Splat for removing an item from an array

Tags: coffeescript

Although I know about splats, still I can't quite grasp the last line from the following code:

```
class Borrowable extends Decorator
  constructor: (@libraryItem) ->

  removeBorrower: (borrower) ->
    @borrowers[t..t] = [] if ( t = @borrowers.indexOf(borrower) ) > -1
```

Btw, this code was copied from https://github.com/aksharp/Design-Patterns/blob/master/CoffeeScript/Decorator.coffee

Im assuming this is [Destructuring Assignment](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring), still I can't quite get my head around what's it's happening behind the scenes.

Could you help clarify this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a closer look at the last line:

```
@borrowers[t..t] = [] if ( t = @borrowers.indexOf(borrower) ) > -1
```

I'm not sure if this form counts as Destructuring Assignment, probably it is.

First, it calls `@borrowers.indexOf(borrower)` to check that `borrower` is present inside of the `@borrowers` array and to get it's index.

It's conventional to use `borrower in @borrowers` form instead of `@borrowers.indexOf(borrower) > -1`, but in this case we need index of an element as well.

If `borrower` is present in `@borrowers`, it gets the part of the `@borrowers` array between indexes `t` and `t`

```
@borrowers[t..t]
```

which is the `[borrower]`, and assigns it to the empty array `[]`, thus removing the `borrower` from `@borrowers` array.

Here is js-like equivalent of this assignment:

```
@borrowers.splice t, 1
```